# PHP loop through array and find highest value

Tags: php, arrays

Hey all i am trying to see what the **highest vote count** is within this array and then get the **file_path** from that.

```
images =>
  backdrops =>
    0 =>
      file_path => /gM3KKiN80qbJgKHjPnmAfwxSicG.jpg
      width => 1920
      height => 1080
      iso_639_1 =>
      aspect_ratio => 1.78
      vote_average => 5.4529616724739
      vote_count => 19
    1 =>
      file_path => /7u3pxc0K1wx32IleAkLv78MKgrw.jpg
      width => 1920
      height => 1080
      iso_639_1 =>
      aspect_ratio => 1.78
      vote_average => 5.4509803921569
      vote_count => 22
    2 =>
      etc etc....
```

I tried doing this but was unable to get any data:

```
foreach($theMovieData['images']['backdrops'][0]['vote_count'] as $key => $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

What would i be doing incorrect? And how would i get the **file_path** after finding the **highest vote**?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do the foreach on `$theMovieData['images']['backdrops']`. you're trying to loop on an integer in that array, not on an array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreach loop is meant to loop through an array, what you are trying to achieve in the code sample posted is a loop in a single variable. You should change the code to something like:

```
$max = 0;
$pathMax = null;
foreach ($theMovieData['images']['backdrops'] as $data){
    $voteCount = $data['vote_count'];
    $path = $data['file_path'];
    if ((int)$voteCount > $max){
        $max = (int)$voteCount;
        $pathMax = $path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate `backdrops`, not `votecount`. Also use a temporary variable to store and compare the previous value.

```
$temp = -1;
foreach($theMovieData['images']['backdrops'] as $key => $item) {

if ($item["vote_count"] > $temp)
$temp = $item["vote_count"];
}
```